# Delete an object from array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete an object in an array in my state. I want to do this by using a onclick handler on items from a map function.

So when I click on a specific item, I have tried many things. I have tried the filter function by trying to pass down the item from the map function and then filtering out the array excluding the item provided as argument, I've tried splice but all doesn't seem to work. With splice, It always delete the last item instead of the Item I click on.

What am I not seeing? I know there are a lot of similiar questions but I've tried many of the answers over there but nothing seems to work.

Filter try

JSX

```
{this.state.product.ingredients.map((item) => {
  return (
     <p className="text-xs text-white bg-brand rounded p-4 mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 inline-block cursor-pointer" key={item.name} onClick={({item}) => this.deleteTag({item})}>{item.name}</p>
  );
})}
```

Method

```
deleteTag(item) {

    let product = {...this.state.product};

    product.ingredients.filter((ingredient) => {
        return ingredient !== item;
    });

    this.setState({product: product});
}
```

Splice

JSX

```
{this.state.product.ingredients.map((item) => {
  return (
     <p className="text-xs text-white bg-brand rounded p-4 mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 inline-block cursor-pointer" key={item.name} onClick={this.deleteTag}>{item.name}</p>
  );
})}
```

Method

```
deleteTag(e) {

    let product = {...this.state.product};

    var index = product.ingredients.indexOf(e.target.value)

    product.ingredients.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({product: product});

}
```

Example of the array with one object (objects/items are added with another function)

```
ingredients: [{name: 'Salad', value: 1}],
```

Comment: For your splice why is `e` not the `item` ? Log it to console will see it is not what you think it is. Then would index `item` in the arrray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are updating your state correctly but instead mutating it. Could you try this:

```
deleteTag(item) {
    this.setState(prevState => { 
      return {
        product: {
           ...prevState.product,
           ingredients: prevState.product.ingredients.filter((ingredient) => ingredient !== item)
        }
      } 
    });
}
```

Edit your onClick to pass the `item` from `map`:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteTag(item)}
```

Comment: Hmm it is returning an error, saying failed to compile. I guess a syntax error?

Comment: in which line? are you sure you have all of files saved?

Comment: @Gijsberts I think an extra bracket was causing that, try the updated snippet.

Comment: Alright I guess the function works except it isn't updating anything. So I guess the filter function is going wrong, because item is I guess undefined or something.. something wrong with the callback. Am I passing it right? (The item)

Comment: @Gijsberts I see, you need to update your `onClick` handler. Checkout the edit.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. It is working now, already thought I was doing something wrong with the argument of item.

Comment: @Gijsberts Cool I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

`filter` returns a new array instead of modifying the array in place.

`{...this.state.product}` only creates a shallow copy, so you should not modify `product.ingredients` in place anyway, which is why your second attempt failed as well.

Try this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  product: { ...prevState.product, ingredients: prevState.product.ingredients.filter(...) },
}));
```

Comment: Hmm it is returning an error, saying failed to compile. I guess a syntax error?

Comment: replace the `filter(...)` with your original `filter` arguments; I used `...` as placeholder for actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `item` to your callback. You're currently using `event.target.value`, but your `<p>` element doesn't have a `value`. Use `bind` to partially apply your callback.

**JSX:**

```
{this.state.product.ingredients.map((item) => (
  <p
    className="text-xs text-white bg-brand rounded p-4 mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 inline-block cursor-pointer"
    key={item.name}
    onClick={this.deleteTag.bind(item)}>
    {item.name}
  </p>
))}
```

the first argument to your callback will be your `item` object because of the partial function application, it'll no longer be the click event. (If you still need the click event, it will be the second argument.)

**Method:**

```
deleteTag(item, /* event */) {
  let product = {...this.state.product};
  const index = product.ingredients.indexOf(item.value)

  product.ingredients.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({product: product});
}
```

Comment: Hey. Got the same result as before, for some reason when I click it will delete/remove the last object in the array, not the one I click on